# Data exchange between forked processes

Tags: ruby

I found out that you can't share variables in any way (not even `$`global ones)and that you must use pipes, so I will cut to the chase.

There are two processes: Process A gets input from somewhere (possibly pipe in the command line) and sends it to Process (fork) B which will print the last given value every second. 
This is basically a simple, basic version of what I need. I tried to do it,but it doesn't show any output. I can't figure out why.

This is the source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

# create two pipes.
reader, writer = IO.pipe

fork do
        loop do
                # print the last received value every second (or so)
                puts "Last name is:  #{reader.read }"
                sleep 1
        end 
end

fork do
ARGF.each_line do |e| 
                name = e.chomp
                #send the data through the pipe
                writer.write name 
        end 

#make sure all forks are killed
Process.waitall
```

In order to get the desired input here is a sample script which you can pipe:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

arr = ['Sally', 'Mike', 'John', 'Steve', 'Iana', 'That guy']

loop do
        puts  arr[rand(5)]
        sleep 1
        STDOUT.flush
end
```

and simply pipe it:

```
./generate_input.rb | ./program.rb
```

Comment: Have you considered [ruby threads](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Thread.html)? You can share variables with threads instead of processes.

Comment: Yes, however as far as I have read, threads in ruby do not run concurrently, but one after the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IO#read` with no length parameter reads until EOF. Since you're not sending EOF (that is, you're not closing the writer), it never returns. You might try something like `reader.gets` and `writer.puts` to write data one line at a time.

Something like this will work as expected:

```
reader, writer = IO.pipe

fork do
  loop do
    # print the last received value every second (or so)
    puts "Last name is:  #{reader.gets }"
    sleep 1
  end
end

fork do
  ARGF.each_line do |e|
    name = e.chomp
    #send the data through the pipe
    writer.puts name
  end
end

#make sure all forks are killed
Process.waitall
```

Comment: Correct! I considered the possibility of the error to be in the IO#read class, though I didn't do enough research on it. Thank you.